# Get latest date in a column

Tags: sqlite, date

I have a bunch of videos with a channelId field and a "createdAt" field with values like:

```
2019-08-13 11:59:46.000000
2019-03-05 18:00:00.000000
2018-12-21 12:14:46.000000
```

Each channelId has at least 1 video, often more. I want the latest video date for each channelId.

My SQLite code:

```
SELECT
julianday(max(v.createdAt, "utc")) AS days
FROM videos v
GROUP BY v.channelId
```

returns NULL for the "days".

But

```
SELECT
julianday(min(v.createdAt, "utc")) AS days
FROM videos v
GROUP BY v.channelId
```

works?

How do I get the latest video upload time? Why does max() return NULL while min() works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this:

```
julianday(max(v.publishedAt), "utc")
```

Your code does not use the aggregation [`max()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) function but the [`max()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc) function that compares values in a list and returns the maximum.
Also:

```
julianday(min(v.publishedAt), "utc")
```

although you say *it works*. It *works* because any datetime value compared as a string is less than the string `"utc"`.